# BigQueue disk space not clearing

Tags: java, queue, message-queue

I am using a java persistence Queue named BigQueue, It stores the data in the disk, bigQueue.gc() is used to clear the used disk space. The big queue.gc() is not clearing the used disk space. The disk memory is continuously increasing.

```
IBigQueue bigQueue = new BigQueueImpl("/home/test/BigQueueNew", "demo1");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        ManagedObject mo = new ManagedObject();
        mo.setName("Aravind " + i);
        bigQueue.enqueue(serialize(mo));
    }

    while (!bigQueue.isEmpty()) {
        ManagedObject mo = (ManagedObject) deserialize(bigQueue.dequeue());
        System.out.println("Key Dqueue ME");
    }
    bigQueue.close(); 

    // bigQueue.removeAll(); bigQueue.gc();; System.out.println("Big Queue is " + bigQueue.isEmpty() +" Size is "+bigQueue.size());
```

Comment: when you finish with the queue, just call the close method to release resource used by the queue - bigQueue.close();

Comment: I have used the close function also, but still, disk memory is not clearing up.

Comment: There must be a memory leak in your program, share your code here.

Comment: IBigQueue bigQueue = new BigQueueImpl("/home/test/BigQueueNew", "demo1");
  for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
  {
   Object mo = new Object();
   //mo.setName("Aravind " + i);
   bigQueue.enqueue(serialize(mo));
  }
  while (!bigQueue.isEmpty())
  {
   ManagedObject mo = (ManagedObject) deserialize(bigQueue.dequeue());
   System.out.println("Key Dqueue ME");
  }
  bigQueue.close();
  // bigQueue.removeAll();
  bigQueue.gc();;
  System.out.println("Big Queue  is " + bigQueue.isEmpty() +" Size is "+bigQueue.size());

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is looking at this as well.

If you are using Java 11 on ubuntu, this could be a known issue. Refer to the link below.

Unless it is fixed at the source, you could download the source and fix it yourself.

https://github.com/bulldog2011/bigqueue/issues/39

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).